# How to make child views automatically take a new line to fit the parent width?

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

First, I want to list tags in a whatever layout. The container's max width is fixed (`match_parent`), and the tags (`TextView`s) should no exceed the right border of the container. Meanwhile, the container is a direct child (`LinearLayout` in my case) of a `ScrollView` (I emphasize this as I find some solutions using customized `onMeasure` and `onLayout` methods extending `ViewGroup`, but cannot work in `ScrollView`).

How can I do this?

Comment: You are looking for `FlowLayout` I guess https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Well, right being reading it while got your comment. And just now tested it - it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved with [`FlowLayout`](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) things, as commented by WaJeEh.